# Lift question bans by answering?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, post-ban

> ### How can I get out of a question ban?
>
> ***Begin by** by improving your existing questions: do as much as possible to make them clear, specific and on-topic.*
>
> [The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines
> that your positive contributions outweigh the cost of those questions
> which were poorly received.](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans)

Does *"begin by"* indicate that answering and other contributions such as edits and comments could also help with lifting a question ban for users who do not have many questions to edit?

Comment: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997) has everything you need to know. Anything else is not public information.